# How to Get Extra Column Value From Stored Procedure using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nopcommerce

Basically i'm using **NopCommerce 3.2**. I have modified the stored procedure so it could return `CategoryName` associated with `Prodcut` details such as;

```
--return products
    SELECT TOP (@RowsToReturn)
        p.*, c.Name as CategoryName
    FROM
        #PageIndex [pi]
        INNER JOIN Product p with (NOLOCK) on p.Id = [pi].[ProductId]
        -- Custom INNER JOIN To Get CategoryName
        INNER JOIN Product_Category_Mapping pc ON pc.ProductId  = p.Id
        INNER JOIN Category c ON c.Id = pc.CategoryId
    WHERE
        [pi].IndexId > @PageLowerBound AND 
        [pi].IndexId < @PageUpperBound
    ORDER BY
        [pi].IndexId
```

As you can see `ResultSet` the `CategoryName` is retrieved;
[image]

In my Code, i have created a custom property with ignor mapping;

```
// Product.cs
public string CategoryName { get; set; }
// another mapping class i.e ProductMapp.cs
this.Ignore(p => p.CategoryName);
```

The actual `ResultSet` is retrieved using this code (minimezed);

```
        // some parameters sent by nopcommerce
        var pTotalRecords = _dataProvider.GetParameter();
        pTotalRecords.ParameterName = "TotalRecords";
        pTotalRecords.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        pTotalRecords.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        .........
        //invoke stored procedure
        var products = _dbContext.ExecuteStoredProcedureList<Product>(
            "ProductLoadAllPaged",
            .............
            .............
            pTotalRecords);
```

The **Method (ExecuteStoredProcedureList)** definition is here; 
**Note: The method code is too long to paste, so i have tried to paste the execution and mapping code only**

```
        //var connection = context.Connection;
        var connection = this.Database.Connection;
        //Don't close the connection after command execution


        //open the connection for use
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();
        //create a command object
        using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            //command to execute
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // move parameters to command object
            if (parameters != null)
                foreach (var p in parameters)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

            //database call
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //return reader.DataReaderToObjectList<TEntity>();
            var result = context.Translate<TEntity>(reader).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                result[i] = AttachEntityToContext(result[i]);
            //close up the reader, we're done saving results
            reader.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

As you can see it is mapping to a `Product` entity. However, in my result set the coloumn can't be mapped automatically, it is always null. I would like to get `CategoryName` coloumn value mapped to `CategoryName` property. How can i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another Class in `Nop.Core` with required field and rather that returning product table return that table. This class can be temporary by creating table in stores procedure itself and dropping at the end.